# com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I'm new to these REST services and I'm getting this exception : com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class XX , and Java type class XX, and MIME media type text/html; charset=utf-8 was not found

and my code is

```
@Path(/test1)
@PUT
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Response write(@Context HttpServletRequest request, EventNotificationType eventNotification)
{
System.out.println("server side.....");
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be many issues, some of which could be:

- You haven't set up your JAXB implementation up to handle that media type (JSON, right?).
- `EventNotificationType` isn't mappable by your JAXB implementation - MOXy for example will silently pass if it has some mapping issues.
- your incoming XML/JSON isn't mappable to `EventNotificationType` - it's a different structure, the fields aren't lining up or have mismatched types.